# Cocos2D iPhone - screen coordinates x sprite's internal coordinates

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2D on iPhone. I see that Cocos2D uses a coordinate axis where 0,0 is at the bottom left corner and X positives are to the right and Y positives up.

Now I have created a sprite and added several sprites as subsprites of this one. For my surprise the subsprites appear mirrored in Y!!! The point 10,10 will be on the upper left corner of the sprite!!!

I can simply flip the sprite in Y to make it follow the same screen coordinate, but then the content will be reversed.

Is this a bug or what?

thanks.

Comment: Without code I am unable to get the problem you are facing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing any example code is a shot in the dark, but I think you need to use Anchor points.

Each sprite has an anchor point of x, y.

ccp(0.5f, 0.5f) would be the center of the sprite.
(0,0) is the bottom left....(1.0f,1.0f) is top right etc....  Over 1.0 goes outside the sprite.

Child nodes (CCSprite) will use their anchor point on the parent node coordinates.

```
MySprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5f,0.5f);
```